# Does lseek work on file redirection?

Tags: c, stdin, io-redirection, seek, fcntl

Usually `lseek` doesn't work on `stdin`.

But, what if I run my program like this:

`./a.out < filename`

Now `stdin` is a file and not keyboard.

Will `lseek` work there?

Can I do

`lseek(0, -1, SEEK_CUR)`

and get the same effect like

`ungetc()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `lseek` will change the seek pointer. No, it is not equivalent to `ungetc()`.

`fseek(stdin, -1, SEEK_CUR)` comes closer to `ungetc()`, but still isn't identical.

Comment: Can I get the effect of `ungetc` using `lseek`?

Comment: Not generally. What effect of `ungetc` are you seeking?

Comment: I am parsing text... I am writing a function like gettoken() from a file. But I am doing < or dup2 and redirecting the file to stdin I am reading token characters and when token is parsed, the last character(one after the token) needs to be pushed back... Is there any system call equivalent to ungetc? because ungetc takes a FILE* arg and I am working on file descriptors...

Comment: If you are `read()`ing the characters from a file descriptor, then yes, `lseek(-1)` has a similar effect with respect to a file descriptor as `ungetc` has with respect to a `FILE*`.

Comment: No I am `getchar`ing it and that's why I am not getting the effect I think write?

Comment: To undo a `ch = getchar()`, you must call `ungetc(ch, stdin)`. You have contradicted yourself: "I am working on file descriptors" is opposite to "I am `getchar`ing it".

Comment: Oh man... I was doing `ungetc(ch, 0)` and getting segmentation fault! You solved my problem bro!!!
`ungetc(ch, stdin)` works like a charm...


Thanks !!!!!!!!!